# D365 CustomJS - Update Field with AutoNumber Field OnSave

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a Autonumber field called 'ID' that generates an ID for a record. I want to set the Primary Name field called 'ID_Name' to this. I am currently using the following JS:

```
function setName(executionContext) {

formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();

var name = formContext.getAttribute("id").getValue();
formContext.getAttribute("id_name").setValue(name);

}
```

Pretty simple. I get the value of 'ID', assign it to a var called name, then set the value of 'ID_Name' to that var. This triggers OnSave.

This works fine when editing a record. The problem is, this does not work when creating a new record. I assume because at the time the OnSave triggers, Autonumber field 'ID' hasn't generated a value which can be used yet, so ID_Name is set to blank. Of course while editing, ID has a value because the record has already been submitted, so no problems. Is there a way around this issue?

Comment: Did you try to set the autonumber on the primary name field in stead? It would save you from duplicating data...

Comment: Tested my earlier suggestion. Works as a charm. Added it as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the OOB autonumber option on the primary name field of your entity. No code required and it saves you from duplicating data, which should be avoided when possible.

Comment: Ah! Perfect, and I can reset the number by adjusting the Seed value of the column. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do some workaround using the OnLoad event and trigger an update when there is a mismatch between the two fields (meaning the value has not been saved) but I strongly suggest to don't use this kind of approach.

Ideally this can be solved using a synchronous plugin inside a post operation, at this moment in the pipeline the id field should be filled (you didn't mention if you are using the OOB autonumber or something different to generate the content of this field) and you can trigger the update inside a plugin.

Comment: Just a OOB Autonumber. Damn.. I was hoping this was going to be simpler.

Comment: you can try also with a synchronous workflow, as the field you mentioned is OOB autonumber and is not the primary guid, you should see it inside the workflow designer, worth a try